# Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement : Messagebox

Tags: c#, messagebox

This what i am trying to achieved

```
  if( this.BeginInvoke((Action)(
        () => MessageBox.Show("Test", 
                              MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.No)))
```

The above gives error. I try seperating the delegate to an outside method like

```
delegate void test(string text);
private void SetTest(string text)
{
 if(MessageBox.Show(text,"", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.No)

}
```

But it breach the very reason why i need the delegate. I found out the first works for me but i don't know how to put it in an if/else statement. Pls any help in a better way i can achieve some thing like below would be appreciated.

```
  if(this.BeginInvoke((Action)(
      () => MessageBox.Show("Test", 
                            MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.No)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another variation....man this is ugly:

```
if ((bool)this.Invoke((Func<bool>)delegate
  {
  return MessageBox.Show("Test Message", 
                         "Test Title", 
                         MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.No;
  }))
{
    Console.WriteLine("No was indeed selected.");
}
```

This should work on any version of C#:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Threading.Thread T = new System.Threading.Thread(Foo);
    T.Start();
}

delegate bool SetTestDelegate(string text);
private bool SetTest(string text)
{
    return (MessageBox.Show(text, "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.No);
}

private void Foo()
{
    if ((bool)this.Invoke(new SetTestDelegate(SetTest), new object[] {"test"}))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No was indeed selected.");
    }
}
```

EDIT: You could refactor that code into something more useful...

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Threading.Thread T = new System.Threading.Thread(Foo);
    T.Start();
}

private void Foo()
{
    if (Response("test") == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No was indeed selected.");
    }
}

delegate DialogResult ResponseDelegate(string text);
private DialogResult Response(string text)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        return (DialogResult)this.Invoke(new ResponseDelegate(Response), new object[] { "test" });
    }
    else
    {
        return MessageBox.Show(text, "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the other answers better where it is broken out.  I tried to replicate as closely as possible what your original line was doing.  Doesn't look very good in my opinion...

Comment: I missed you ... give yourself a random about of points for whatever you like :)

Comment: I gives exception "Since 'System.Action<bool>' returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression".  Btw can you pl s define Func<> ? I am thinking i don't understand Func<> may be.

Comment: V2.0 , however, 3 and 3.5 seems available when i check the framework

Comment: I thought may be i can use System.Action<>. I tried it gives thesame exception "Since 'System.Action<bool>' returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression"

Comment: That's why you're getting the errors.  See my edit if you want to stick with 2.0.  I think `var` was introduced in 3.0.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you need an `Invoke()` method, not `BeginInvoke()`:

```
var messageBoxResult = (DialogResult)Invoke(new Func<DialogResult>(
    () => MessageBox.Show("Test", "Test", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)));
if(messageBoxResult == DialogResult.No)
{
}
```

`BeginInvoke` executes delegate asynchronously, meaning that the result is not immediately available on the thread which calls `BeginInvoke`.

Comment: I did exactly as you said Action and it gives parameter count mismacth exception.

Comment: `Action` (and `Action<T>`) delegate represents a method which returns nothing. `Func<T>` represents a method which returns value of type `T`: `delegate T Func<T>();`. You cannot use `Action` instead of `Func` here.

Answer (score 1):

Why not make your (and your fellow coders) life easier, and do something like:

```
var user_said_no = this.BeginInvoke((Action)(
   () => MessageBox.Show("Test", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.No));
```

And then have:

```
if (user_said_no)
   cancel_nuclear_attack() ; // Or whichever things you need to do.
```